# HTML editable Table -> get edited Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML-Table

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Smith</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Jackson</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Just a TEST-Table)

It is editable, but how do I get all the rows (with ID) which were edited, to send them to a PHP-Backend which saves the changes to DB?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick.

Comment: You can loop trhough table, get needed data, and then, send it to your server.

Comment: But how can I find out, which columns were edited?

Comment: You could always create a log that stores what has been modified, logs are always good to have.

Comment: And which event is fired, when an Column is edited?

Comment: I assume you haven't actually set anything up database side?

Comment: You can then, loop through data on load, then loop throug data before send... and determine wich fields were changed. Or use the html5 `input`  event

Comment: Nope, cause I wanted that if a column is edited and a save-Button is pressed, all changes will be sent with javascript over POST to a PHP-Backend which saves the changes to DB.

Comment: Thats why you need input event, you detect and track which data was changed, and then send it on the save button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save ids in an Array whenever field content is changed.
Here is the Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/79egs9tc/

```
var idArr = [];
$(".edited").focusout(function() {
     var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
     if($.inArray(id, idArr) === -1){
        idArr.push(id);
     }
     console.log(idArr);
});
```

You can add check for content is changes or not.
Hope, it will work for you.